# SQL Server Express: How to determine SP memory usage

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am developing with Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

I have a stored procedure that uses temp tables and outputs some processed data usually within 1 second.

Over a few months, my DB has gathered a lot of data almost reaching the 10 GB limit. At this point, this particular stored procedure started taking as much as 5 mins for the same input parameters. After I emptied some of the huge tables in DB, it got back to normal.

After this incident, I am worried if my stored procedure needs more than necessary space in DB. How can I be sure? Any leads?

Thanks already
Jyotsna

Comment: Are your index statistics current? Does your SP suffer from a stale, parameter sniffed, execution plan? Have you looked at the execution plan?

Comment: Check for optimization of Sql Server. Also look into clustering.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3687186/Monitoring-Stored-Procedure-Usage.htm)

Other old school way is run `spwho2` check your spid related to the database see CPU and IO usage.

To validate run `DBCC INPUTBUFFER(spid)`

Also check STATISTICS of SP in original scenario without purging data from tables.

SET STATISTICS IO ON
EXEC [YourSPName]

see the logical reads , also refer [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/simple-query-tuning-with-statistics-io-and-execution-plans/)